# How to get the string version of an enum?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model enum like:

```
class User < AR::Base
  enum status [:pending, :member, :banned]
end
```

Now I want to output the string value of 'banned' but it outputs the int value:

```
User.statuses[:banned]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that's how they work. Looking at some docs:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

You would have something like

```
# User.status = 2
User.status = "banned"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something of a non-answer, but the question belies the implementation of [ActiveRecord::Enum](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html):

```
# to get the string value for User.statuses[:banned]…
"banned"
# or
:banned.to_s

# to get the string value for all values in the User.statuses enum…
User.statuses.keys
# => ["pending", "member", "banned"]
```

The key isn't the important part here, really. All Rails is doing is taking the array of symbols you give it here…

```
enum status: [:pending, :member, :banned]
```

…and assigning it to a hash with incremented integer values while providing you a bunch of convenient methods for accessing the value:

```
user.status #=> 'pending'
user.pending? #=> true
```

You can verify this if you like…

```
User.defined_enums.class #=> Hash
User.defined_enums
#=> { "status" => { "pending" => 0, "member" => 1, "banned" => 2 } }
```